# Getting undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in ruby implementation of quicksort algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, quicksort

This is my code for the quicksort algorithm:

```
def partition(quick, l, h)
  x = quick[h]
  i = l-1
  j = 0

  (0..h-1).each do |j|
    if quick[j] < x
      i = i+1
      quick[i], quick[j] = quick[j], quick[i]
    end
  end

  quick[i+1], quick[h] = quick[h], quick[i+1]

  return i+1
end

def quickSort(quick, l, h)
  if l < h
    p = partition(quick, l, h)
    quickSort(quick, l, p-1)
    quickSort(quick, p+1, h)
  end
end

quick = Array[10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5]

n = quick.size
quickSort(quick, 0, n-1)
puts "Sorted Array"

def printArray(quick)
  quick.each do |i|
    puts quick[i]
  end
end

printArray(quick)
```

I am getting the following error after running the program:

```
 quick.rb:9:in `block in partition': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from quick.rb:8:in `each'
from quick.rb:8:in `partition'
from quick.rb:24:in `quickSort'
from quick.rb:25:in `quickSort'
from quick.rb:26:in `quickSort'
from quick.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Help me to find what am I doing wrong? Please give the explaination of the error which has ocurred in my implementation of the algorithm

Comment: Sometimes `quick[j]` returns `nil`. Debug your code.

Comment: Use snake_case for methods.